# How do I make a List show up on the Quick Navigation section?

Tags: list

How do I make a SharePoint 2013 List show up on the Quick Navigation section on the left hand side?

Also, do all Lists I create show up as app boxes? In other words, is that an automatic default setting?

Thanks

Answer (score 5):

Please follow below steps:

- Click **`"List Setting"`**
- Click **`"Title, description and navigation"`**
- Select **`"YES"`** for **`"Display this document library on the Quick Launch?"`**
- Now your list will be shown in your Quick Launch.

If Still its not showing your list then follow below steps:

- Open **`Site Setting`**
- Click on **`Tree View`** under **`Look and Feel`** section.
- Check the box which says **`Enable Quick Launch`**

Answer (score 2):

I found the answer. After choosing a Name I select Advanced Options. Once there is a Navigation section. I have the option to "Display this list in the Quick Launch section. I simply choose Yes for it to show up on Quick Launch, or No for it not to.